# How to find IP address or Location of http request?

Tags: java, javascript

I want to find location of http request that are coming from many countries. i am getting ip address of http request by using javascript but i want to find location of that **ip address or country** of that ip address is there any java API to do that. or any other way like google API to find location

THANKS in advance...

Comment: Have you tried searching like this : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=geo+location+ip+address (This is a common question here) And also see http://www.google.co.in/search?q=html+5+geo+location&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GeoIP API to do that for you:
https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/

Answer (score 1):

Doing a search on Google for GEOIP API will provide you with a number of options, including [IPLocationTools](http://www.iplocationtools.com/api.html#b) which has a Javascript API.